# executemany with pyodbc, stored procedures and SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc

I would be grateful to know what is the easiest way to diagnose this error, as it does not seem to be easy to display what SQL is being executed via pyodbc.

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[s_populate_Test_sp]  
    @TestDateTime DATETIME, 
    @TestInt INT, 
    @TestMoney MONEY, 
    @TestVarChar500 VARCHAR(500), 
    @TestFloat FLOAT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Test_sp2] (test_datetime, test_int, test_money, test_varchar500, test_float)
    VALUES (@TestDateTime, @TestInt, @TestMoney, @TestVarChar500, @TestFloat)
```

I can execute this stored procedure once successfully using raw text (the commented code below), but I am having difficulty with executemany:

```
import os 
import pyodbc
import datetime
        
def test_sp():
    # Constants
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    
    # Connect
    server = 'xxx'
    db2 = 'xxx'
    conn_str = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + \
                           ';DATABASE=' + db2 + ';Trusted_Connection=yes'
    conn=pyodbc.connect(conn_str, autocommit=False)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.fast_executemany = True
    
    for row in range(10000):
        # sql = '''EXEC [dbo].[s_populate_Test_sp] @TestDateTime = '2020-01-01 13:00',
        #             @TestInt = 999,
        #             @TestMoney = '£12.34',
        #             @TestVarChar500 = 'Hello My Name is Jon',
        #             @TestFloat = 1.234567
        #             '''
        # cursor.execute(sql)
        

        sql = '''exec s_populate_Test_sp (@TestDateTime = ?, @TestInt = ?, @TestMoney = ?, @TestVarChar500 = ?, @TestFloat = ?)'''
        values = ['2020-01-01 13:00', 999, '£12.34', 'Hello My Name is Jon', 1.234567]
        cursor.executemany(sql, [values])
        
    conn.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_sp()
```

Unfortunately this yields a rather cryptic error message:

> ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@TestDateTime'. (102) (SQLExecute); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

I can't find a way of displaying the SQL before it gets executed, so it's all a bit trial and error at the moment.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you notice a difference between the code that works and the code that doesn't? I do. `@TestDateTime` vs. `(@TestDateTime`.

Comment: Thanks.  Once I remove the parentheses.  I get:
`DataError: ('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid character value for cast specification (0) (SQLExecute)')`

I thought then it might be the £ sign, so I removed that.  Still get the error.  Will investigate further.

Comment: Suggest using a datetime format that is standard and unambiguous, either `yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss` or `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`. Might also check if `tbl_Test_sp2` has a trigger.

Comment: Solved it thanks - if I use a datetime.datetime object and remove the £ sign it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments, the answer was to remove the parentheses, the £ sign and use a datetime.datetime object:

```
sql = '''exec s_populate_Test_sp @TestDateTime = ?, @TestInt = ?, @TestMoney = ?, @TestVarChar500 = ?, @TestFloat = ?'''
values = [datetime.datetime.now(), 999, 12.34, 'Hello My Name is Jon', 1.234567]
```

It is frustrating that it is so slow.  Over my firm's VPN it can do 400 records per minute and on a virtual machine close to the server it can do 9,000 records per minute.  I suspect this is one of the limitations of pyodbc and SQL Server, and I will have to do bcp or something like that for larger datasets.